# Dynamically call method name?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is function:

```
def runaction(ENV, action_list):

    appmanage_list = ['status']

    for action in action_list.keys():
        print('Action: %s' % action)

        if action in appmanage_list:

            from lib import appmanage_functions
            a = appmanage_functions.AppManage(ENV)
            a.[SOMETHING_GOES_HERE](ENV)
```

It's called like:

```
 runaction(env, main_f.opts2)
```

`action_list` (`main_f.opts2` argument in function call) - is dictionary from `argparse` with `{'optionname':True}`;

`appmanage_list` - will include all options, which need to be call with code above;

`action` - options name, same as method from `appmanage_functions.AppManage` class, need to be called.

In place of *[SOMETHING_GOES_HERE]* I want add `action` variable, to call appropriate method from class.

I tried something like:

```
(a. + action + (ENV))
```

and:

```
a.('%s' % action)(ENV)
```

But sure - this not works...

Python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`object.foo` can be rephrased as [`getattr(object, 'foo')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr).

So you can say:

```
getattr(a, action)(ENV)
```